# Ionic iOS White Status Bar

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

So I'm currently having an issue with the status bar when trying to use my app on Ionic Viewer App, seems that even when I try to set a new style of the status bar, in iOS the background color it's kinda transparent but I want it to match the color of the header so both get fusioned making it look awesome. Any way to change the color of the status bar to blue and the text to white? I searched and tried to get this but didn't seem to work:

[Status bar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shb7a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu" color="light"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="search" color="light"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Colors used in variables.scss

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #2196F3,
  secondary:  #ff307f,
  danger:     #f44336,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

Here is the image which shows how does this look like in android and iphone devices:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure I'm putting this correctly, I putted it on my template.html but didn't work, where should I try this code?